# Any other ways to write app for Surface RT instead of Windows Store app?

Tags: windows-rt

Is it possible to write a console EXE app like "hello, world!" for Surface RT?

I thought it suffice to compile it for ARM, but it seems there's no such compile option.

I installed Office 2013 RT and I found the Excel.exe. So can I write such EXE, too?

If only Windows Store app is allowed for Surface RT, why provide a "desktop" ?

Answer (score 4):

No it is not allowed. The reason desktop mode exists is most likely so you can use Office on the RT device. But otherwise, they are locking down the device so you cannot do all that crazy Win32 stuff that can kill performance and battery on an RT device.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write sophisticated HTML websites that behave like apps like this: https://www.pulse.me/
Websites in IE10 can

1. Have a snapped mode
2. Have a large tile
3. have a badge number indicator

http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/ for more details.